# Text in Google Chrome is blurry / fuzzy

Tags: google-chrome, fonts, rendering

I've searched all over for an answer to this and surprisingly, I can't find one. I've had a look at the following questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32034574/font-looks-blurry-after-translate-in-chrome), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11745239/font-face-fonts-showing-blurred-on-mac-in-safari-and-chrome) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27385126/chrome-font-appears-blurry). All of those questions though refer to transforming/rotating the text in some fashion which is not something I'm even doing.

This is what the text currently looks like. As you can see in Chrome, it's blurry and in Firefox it's crisp and looks good. I'm using Google Fonts and specifically using the Oxygen font.

[image]

I've also tried using `text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;` as well on the body tag and also on the specific element with no luck [from this article](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/text-rendering/).

I've had no luck at all, am I missing something really, really obvious?

Comment: Did you have this problem before? What OS did you use? Have you tried another fonts? (PT Sans and PT Serif are quite good from the free).

Comment: Those look like differently kerned fonts to me, are you sure you're actually loading the same one for both browsers? (where's your CSS that sets up the font rules?)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, that is really reaching there.

Comment: @AdrianM. no it isn't, it's a basic debugging question. There is no code, the fonts look spaced completely different, and so verifying that the exact same fonts are being loaded is a trivial first step.

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue with the [Anton font](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Anton). Yes, both browsers are definitely using the same font files.